# css hovering in the wrong position on wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm working on resolving this hover issue on my site. Whenever I roll over a product, the product description shows up underneath it and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it:

http://lovelylovely.me/shop/

It's using the sentient theme but after spending some time in firebug trying to dig into the css, I'm still unable to figure out how to move the the product description so that it shows up on top of the image instead of underneath it.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: With out the CSS it is difficult to diagnose the issue, however have you tried adding a negative top margin to the description container? for instance if the image height is 150px try setting a margin to description container to 'margin-top: -150px;'

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. Here are the paths to the relevant css files: http://lovelylovely.me/wp-content/themes/sentient/style.css  and http://lovelylovely.me/wp-content/themes/sentient/css/layout.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
// removes img from the flow, so doesn't push other elements down:
.product > img{position:absolute;z-index:1} 

//on hover, give the other elements positioning & z-index 
// so they're not hidden by the image:
.product:hover h3,
.product:hover .amount,
.product:hover .excerpt,
.product:hover .button add_to_cart_button product_type_simple
    {position:relative;z-index:2}
```

Comment: thanks, which file were you referring to for that change? and just so it's clear, you're saying add that that new css info to those class definitions?

Comment: Yes, add that CSS. I would add the declarations to a CSS file that is not part of the plugin, if you have one already with your own specific declarations. That way if you need to update the plugin by replacing its files, you won't lose the fix. Technically, it won't matter which file you put them in, and I don't have a handle on the various CSS files you have included here.